# Find the longest repeating string and the number of times it repeats in a given string

Tags: c, algorithm

For example, given string "**abc fghi bc kl abcd lkm abcdefg**", the function should return string "**abcd**" and the count of 2.

A O(n^2) solution seems easy but I am looking for a better solution.

**Edited:** If nothing better than O(n^2) is possible than which approach would be best performance wise.

Comment: Your SO user name is a bit of a give away.

Comment: thats intentional to ward off the SNOBS.

Comment: Longest repeated substring problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can solve this in linear time by building a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) and taking a path from the root to the deepest internal node; this will give you the longest repeated string. Once you have that string, it's trivial to count the number of times it appears.

Answer (score 2):

A state machine could probably give something better than big-O(N^2).

EDIT: The suffix tree suggested in the other answer is such an implementation of a state machine :)